# How to uninstall a Mylyn connector not working

Tags: eclipse, bitbucket, mylyn, connector

I recently updated my Eclipse to Juno release.
I had a working Mylyn Connector for Bitbucket installed and it worked in Helios.
After the upgrade the Bitbucket repository is gone and when I try to add a new repository for Bitbucket no connector is available.
Trying to install the connector from Bitbucket, Eclipse tells me it is already installed.
When viewing the all installed software I see Mylyn Bitbucket Connector but the Uninstall button is disabled.

As far as I know it is not the preferred solution to remove files from plugins/ or features/ directory.

How can I uninstall this Mylyn Connector?

I'm running 32-bit Eclipse Java EE on Win7

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer an issue.
I have huge inconsistencies in my Juno installation (continuing) but after a one on one update of updates I got it working again.